# Suddenly lost almost 500 reputation

Tags: soporte, reputación

Earlier today, my reputation total was 3,021 (as my meta user now shows). However, the main site now lists it as 2,546. I've heard something about reputation recalculation causing small variances in rep. totals, but this is a major difference. What could cause this to happen?

Comment: Check out this question:  [Dissapearing reputation](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1948/3954), specially Shog9's  answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Ah ok, I guess since I'm asking a majority of the questions people's voting is getting marked as suspicious. Oh well...

Comment: Yes, I guess that that is what happened.

Comment: Just lost 500 or so again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a script that looks for "suspicious" voting patterns between users. The details are kept intentionally vague, and normally you shouldn't ever be aware of it.

Normally reputation does fluctuate by much smaller amounts, but in this case it looks like someone just got too enthusiastic and upvoted enough of your posts to make the script think something untoward was going on.